# How to create a event on separate page Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, getelementbyid

I'm trying to figure out how to create a event on a separate page from my index page below. For instance when a click event occurs I want to append a new node on a separate page (artist.html) I know I can access the Element ID and append the child,  but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here,
Real world example: User clicks on a element that becomes an click event, that takes them to a page that creates a text node saying "Hello World"...
Below is a snippet of my Javascript code.

index.html page where the click event occurs is below:

```
      <form class="navbar-search">
                <input class="search-query" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
                <div id="drop" class="dropdown">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li>
                           <a id="photo_0" tabindex="-1" href="artist.html">
                              <p id="artist_0" class="list-item"> </p>
                           </a>
                        </li>
                       <li>
                           <a id="photo_1" tabindex="-1" href="artist.html">
                             <p id="artist_1" class="list-item"> </p>
                           </a>
                        </li>
     
    <script>
   
    var photo0 = document.getElementById("photo_0");
    photo0.onclick = function() {

document.getElementById("album0").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello  World"));

};
```

Snippet of the artist.html page where I want to append the new text node when the event click occurs created above

```
     <a href="#"><p id="album0" class="album-photo"></p></a>
        <div>
            <p id="album-data0" class="albumdata-class"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: If `artist.html` is not open at the time the change is to be made there's no way to do this. If it's open in a different window this is possible if you have an identifier for the window. More detail required!

Comment: @ Mike ...So theres no way to create a new text node from an element on another page off an event click??, it would be pretty much like a dynamic page... where i add and remove child elements from click events

Comment: @Mike Im assuming a click event cannot occur through two pages at once..  1) click event occurs 2) user goes to certain page, 3) user sees a new text node that was dynamically created with javascript..???

Comment: If a page is not open it's not available in the DOM, so you can't add an element to it. If the page is open (if, say, you used `myWindow = window.open(...)`) then you can add an element to it with `myWindow.document.getElementById('id').appendChild();` However, pop-up windows like this are ugly at best You're quite right - an event only occurs in one place. What you could do is use the event to redirect to `artist.html` using a querystring to pass the information about the change, and get javascript on the new page to implement the change. This does all seem a bit cumbersome, though.

Comment: @ Mike Wooooaa,that is alot... thank GOD for Backbone.js lol... thanks so much for your explanation ... :)

Answer (score 0):

could you create a parameter in the URL that could be pulled into the new page, and have the event created from the parameter? (e.g. www.whatever.com?someparameter=whatever)

Comment: @ Tom, im not sure, but backbone.js will fix all of this, im trying to dynamically add and remove dom elements from another page,

Answer (score 0):

To do this, commence a new window if not already.

```
var newwindow = window.open(url);
```

Make sure to store it into a variable. Then, execute this JavaScript:

```
newwindow.document.body.appendChild(element);
```

The document.body is the newly opened window, and can be accessed via the variable.